# Export database with JFileChooser as excel

Tags: java

As you can see i am using FileOutputStream to save the database but it saves  into a specific place. I want to use JFileChooser but i don't know how exactly...Can anyone help me?

```
Statement stm52 = conn.obtenirconnexion().createStatement();
ResultSet rs052 = stm52.executeQuery("Select * from testinsert where pid='" + lastid + "'");
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("testinsert");
HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Found");
rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Name");
rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("Pid");
int i = 1;
while (rs052.next()) {
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
    row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs052.getString("found"));
    row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs052.getString("name"));
    row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs052.getInt("pid")));
    i++;
    String sv = "C://Users//DM//Documents//NetBeansProjects//An//src//an//TXT//test.xls";
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(sv);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code to select a destination file, and write to it .

Also beware, in your case you should create the `OutputStream` and the writing part outside of your `while` loop, or you will overwrite the file for each row read  (I updated the code accordingly).

```
   File sv= null;

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

               sv= chooser.getSelectedFile();


            }
           else{

            // no file has been chosen
            return;
           }

    while (rs052.next()) {
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
        row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs052.getString("found"));
        row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs052.getString("name"));
        row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs052.getInt("pid")));
        i++;



    }

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(sv);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

Comment: And with `setFileFilter`  i convert it to excel?

Comment: A FileFilter will force an extension, but you are responsible for the way you write the file (or the way HSSFWorkbook writes a file).